# Infinite scrolling -- category preblem

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am trying to set infinite scroll on web,i used it on main page all works fine content load good but when i use it on category page "i use accordeon menu" its not work and says WRONG! code: workscript.js

```
var page;
var param = location.
search.
slice(location.search.indexOf('?')+1).
split('&');
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < param.length;i++) {
var res = param[i].split('=');
result[res[0]] = res[1];
}

if(result['page']) {
page = result['page'];
}
else {
page = 1;
}
$(".pager1").show().text(page);

var block = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {

if($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() &&
!block) {
block = true;
$(".load1").fadeIn(500, function () {
page++;
$.ajax({
url:"index.php",
type:"GET",
data:"page="+page+"&move=1",
success:function(html) {
if(html) {
$(html).appendTo($("#content")).hide().fadeIn(1000);
$(".pager1").text(page);
}
$(".load1").fadeOut(500);
block = false;
}
});
});
}
});
```

model.php

```
function productsbase($category, $start_pos, $perpage){
$query = "(SELECT goods_id, name, img, anons, price, hits, new, sale, date
FROM goodsbase
WHERE goods_brandid = $category AND visible='1')
UNION      
(SELECT goods_id, name, img, anons, price, hits, new, sale, date
FROM goodsbase 
WHERE goods_brandid IN 
(
SELECT brand_id FROM brandsbase WHERE parent_id = $category
) AND visible='1') ORDER BY goods_id LIMIT $start_pos, $perpage";
$res = mysql_query($query);

if (!$res){
exit("<p>WRONG!!!</p>");
}
if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
exit(false);
}
$productsbase = array();
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($res); $i++) {
$productsbase[] = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
}          
return $productsbase;
}
```

controller.php

```
case('catbase'):
$category = abs((int)$_GET['category']);
$perpage = 6; 
$start_pos = ($page - 1) * $perpage; 

$brandbase_name = brandbase_name($category); 
$productsbase = productsbase($category, $start_pos, $perpage);
$meta['title'] = $brandbase_name[0]['brand_name'];
if($brandbase_name[1]) $meta['title'] .= " - {$brandbase_name[1] 
['brand_name']}";
$meta['title'] .= " | " .TITLE;
$meta['description'] = "{$brandbase_name[0]['brand_name']},  
{$brandbase_name[1]['brand_name']}";
break;
```

and TOP OF controller.php

```
if($_GET['page']) {
$page = (int)$_GET['page'];
if(!$page) {
    $page = 1;
}
}
else {
$page = 1;
}

$perpage = 6;
$start_pos = ($page - 1) * $perpage;
$productsbase = productsbase($category, $start_pos, $perpage); 

if($productsbase && $_GET['move'] == 1) {
foreach($productsbase as $productbase) {
printf("<div class='product-index'>
<div class='Complogo'>
<img src='%simages/Company-logo.png' />
<h2><a href='%sproductbase/%s'>%s</a></h2>

</div>
<div class='product-table-img'>
<a href='%sproductbase/%s'><img class='top' src='%s%s' alt='' /></a>
</div> <!-- .product-table-img -->
<div class='statsbcgbase'><div class='shape'><img src='%simages/larig.png'
/></div>
<p>PRICE:<span>%s</span></p>


</div>
</div>",TEMPLATE,PATH,$productbase['goods_id'],$productbase['name'],PATH,$pr    oductbase['goods_id'],PRODUCTIMG,$productbase['img'],TEMPLATE,
$productbase['price']);
}
exit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code is updating the `.load1`, `#content` and `.pager1` elements on the page. But you PHP template doesn't have these elements.

You need to add these elements to your page. Try to add the follow elements to your page:

```
<div class='load1'>
<div id='content'>
<div class='pager1'>
```

After you add these elements the script should start work. You just need to make it fits correctly with your design.

Comment: yes its have.  this code is only for updating and original code is on content element

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see it on your snippet above.

Comment: i use this javascript for main page like this and all works fine. i think problem is on mysql but i didint know why